# Remove nested list if nested list contains a number at an index

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, typeerror, nested-lists

I want to remove a nested list of numbers if that nested list contains a specific number at a specific index.

Sample list of lists:

```
permutations_list = [[9, 7, 14, 4, 2, 10], [9, 7, 2, 10, 14, 4], [9, 7, 2, 10, 4, 14], [9, 7, 2, 14, 10, 4], [9, 7, 2, 14, 4, 10], [9, 7, 2, 4, 10, 14], [9, 7, 2, 4, 14, 10], [9, 7, 4, 10, 14, 2], [9, 7, 4, 10, 2, 14], [9, 7, 4, 14, 10, 2], [9, 7, 4, 14, 2, 10], [9, 7, 4, 2, 10, 14], [9, 7, 4, 2, 14, 10]]
```

What I would like is to check if each nested list contains the number 14 at index 4. If that occurs, remove any nested list that meets those specifications resulting in the following list of lists:

```
permutations_list = [[9, 7, 14, 4, 2, 10], [9, 7, 2, 10, 4, 14], [9, 7, 2, 14, 10, 4], [9, 7, 2, 14, 4, 10], [9, 7, 2, 4, 10, 14], [9, 7, 4, 10, 2, 14], [9, 7, 4, 14, 10, 2], [9, 7, 4, 14, 2, 10], [9, 7, 4, 2, 10, 14]]
```

Here's what I tried:

```
for i in permutations_list:
    for c in i:
        if c =='10' and c[4]:
            permutations_list.remove(i)
```

All this does is result in:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
permutations_list = [[9, 7, 14, 4, 2, 10], [9, 7, 2, 10, 14, 4], [9, 7, 2, 10, 4, 14], [9, 7, 2, 14, 10, 4], [9, 7, 2, 14, 4, 10], [9, 7, 2, 4, 10, 14], [9, 7, 2, 4, 14, 10], [9, 7, 4, 10, 14, 2], [9, 7, 4, 10, 2, 14], [9, 7, 4, 14, 10, 2], [9, 7, 4, 14, 2, 10], [9, 7, 4, 2, 10, 14], [9, 7, 4, 2, 14, 10]]
permutations_list = [i for i in permutations_list if not i[4] == 14]
print(permutations_list)
```

---

Or using `filter`

```
permutations_list = list(filter(lambda x: x[4] != 14, permutations_list))
```

**Output:**

```
[[9, 7, 14, 4, 2, 10],
 [9, 7, 2, 10, 4, 14],
 [9, 7, 2, 14, 10, 4],
 [9, 7, 2, 14, 4, 10],
 [9, 7, 2, 4, 10, 14],
 [9, 7, 4, 10, 2, 14],
 [9, 7, 4, 14, 10, 2],
 [9, 7, 4, 14, 2, 10],
 [9, 7, 4, 2, 10, 14]]
```

Comment: Both work perfectly. Although, it seems slightly faster to use `filter` when running through my large data pool. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can just loop through the main list once and check if the element at index 4 in this list is 14 or not. if it is 14, remove it, if not, do nothing. like I did below

```
for i in permutations_list :
   if i[4] == 14 :
      permutations_list.remove(i)
```